# Sending transactional SMS from rails app in India

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms, twilio

I'm developing a rails app in which sends an SMS to the user for some action done by the user.

Now I know that there is a restriction on the outgoing promotional SMS in India. But this message of mine if something like a transactional SMS which is triggered based on a user action and needs to be delivered without any time restriction (9am-9pm). I also want the SMS ID to be alphanumeric on the user side.

Right now I'm using Twilio.

```
  client = Twilio::REST::Client.new Rails.application.secrets.twilio_account_sid, Rails.application.secrets.twilio_auth_token
  message = client.messages.create from: 'XXXXXXXX', to: 'XXXXXXXX', body: 'Message body for the transaction.'
```

I went through their docs but couldn't get to what I wanted.

**My question in short is that:**

- Can I use twilio for my case in India? If yes, how? And if not, which service should I use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm Megan from Twilio.

By default, all SMS messages sent from Twilio phone numbers in India are categorized as “Promotional”. You can read a bit more about the resulting limitations in our [FAQ](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices). These are limitations and regulations set up by Indian government. Our support team can help determine whether we can get you set up on "Transactional" messaging if you email help@twilio.com.

Hope this helps!